# Directions based on polygon centroid and average/median point of adjacent polygon's touching border

Tags: qgis, centroids, direction, borders, adjacency

I have a layer containing multiple polygons, and I am trying to find a way to identify the directions of the adjacent polygons of a certain polygon. The directions would be based on the main polygon centroid (red dot) and the average/center point (blue dot) of the touching polygon's line:

[image: Directions based on polygon centroid and average point of adjacent polygon's touching border]

Is there any script, plugin, or algorithm that accomplishes this, preferably one that can do it in batch?